# Google Docs Viewer gives javascript error inside ASP.Net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, master-pages, google-docs

I'm trying to embed google docs viewer in my page. 
Here's the test.aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web_Application.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe id="documentLoader" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://view.samurajdata.se/license.pdf"
 style="width:100%; height:800px;">
 </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my test.aspx.cs

```
namespace Web_Application
{
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I get errors such as

```
'Line: 409
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'k': object is null or undefined'
```

or

```
'Line: 458
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'a': object is null or undefined'
```

which are from google doc viewer online javascript resource...

So I embedded the script in the header and it worked. But the problem is, if I do this in a user control or in a page inherited from a master page I get those errors again.

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: If you found a solution on this problem on your own, please update this question with your own answer and mark it as accepted. This will also improve your low accept rating.

Answer (score 0):

try this iframe script independent of any browser or version this will work ....

```
<iframe id="documentLoader" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://view.samurajdata.se/license.pdf&chrome=true" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;">
</iframe>
```

mark yes if works !!! :)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. I just get more java script errors. I need to look for someone who has tried this on ASP.NET explicitly.

Comment: did u type that url in browser any try ... do u have any error

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="documentLoader"
        src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http//view.samurajdata.se/license.pdf&embedded=true"
        style="width:100%; height:800px;">
```

Comment: To format code blocks indent each line with four spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help